# Print undefined in console with no reason, Javascript

Tags: javascript, console, closures, undefined

I have the below block of code which in the console print "**undefine**" twice after "Hello"

**JavaScript Code**

```
function f()
{
     function g() {
        console.log("Hello");
    }
    return g;
}

var x = f()();
console.log(x);
```

While I am trying to print only "Hello", where is the two **undefined** printing from

**Output in console**

```
 Hello
 undefined
 undefined
```

Comment: What is your question? The first `undefined` appears, because `g` doesn’t return anything, the second one because `console.log` doesn’t return anything.

Answer (score 1):

The first `undefined` is because `f()()` evaluates to whatever `g` returns, and `g` doesn't return anything. You store that `undefined` in `x`, then print it when you write `console.log(x);`.

I'm guessing the second `undefined` is the result of running this in a console. The last line containing `console.log` evaluates to `undefined`, which may be implicitly printed from the console/REPL. You can confirm this by adding something like the string `"World"` as the last line of the script. Adding anything else to the last line should get rid of the second `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if I remove x and change it to console.log(f()()), it would print the same. Interestingly undefined is printed twice in chrome console, if I execute in node it prints only once.

Comment: @ningomba2.0 That code you changed it to is the same as your old code, just without the intermediate `x` variable. I'll modify the wording in my answer. Basically, `f()()` returns undefined since `g` doesn't return anything. In your first bit of code, you stored that undefined in x. In your new code, you give that undefined straight to `console.log`. Here's a question: in your first code, what do you expect `x` to hold?

Comment: @ningomba2.0 `f()()` is `undefined`, since `g` doesn't return anything.

Comment: @Carcigenicate, Thank you very much, I got your point, I was using x to check the difference between the two, one by assigning the result of f()() and printing x and the other by directly printing f()().